# How do i extract DateTime values from SharePoint list in c# using EventReceiver?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am developing a Sharepoint site for Leave Management.
I want to validate start date and end date entered by the user from a SharePoint List(no. of days the leave is applied should pe less than the no. of leaves available). How do i extract DateTime values from SharePoint list? And how do i subtract 2 DateTime values to get the difference(no. of days)?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't try it but it should be something like this.. This is for ItemAdded. You should do this for item update method also.

```
public class ItemEvents : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        DateTime startDate = (DateTime)item["StartDate"];
        DateTime endDate = (DateTime)item["EndDate"];
        TimeSpan difference = endDate - startDate;
        item["DayCount"] = difference.Days;
        item.Update();
    }
}
```